# Pyttsx3 cutting out some speech?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyttsx3

So I'm using the pyttsx3 method to convert some text into a file.
My code is as such

```
text = open('script.txt','r').read()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.save_to_file(text,'audio.wav')

engine.runAndWait()
```

The file saves but it will randomly stop at periods and commas ie. Script is 'Hi. How are you doing?' but the audio is 'Hi.'
Does this have anything to do with my system?
How would I remedy this?

Comment: on Linux it gives me correct results